# Observable is not assignable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I get following error while I assign observable to my list:

[image]

I might be missing a trick which I am unable to figure out.Would be great if someone can put some insight on that.Here is my app-data file:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import {Lesson} from "../shared/model/lesson";
import {Subject, Observable, Observer} from 'rxjs';


class DataStore {

    private lessons : Lesson[]  = [];

    private lessonsListSubject = new Subject();

    public lessonsList$: Observable<Lesson[]> = this.lessonsListSubject.asObservable();

    initializeLessonsList(newList: Lesson[]) {
        this.lessons = _.cloneDeep(newList);
        this.broadcast();
    }

    addLesson(newLesson: Lesson) {
        this.lessons.push(_.cloneDeep(newLesson));
        this.broadcast();
    }

    deleteLesson(deleted:Lesson) {
        _.remove(this.lessons,
            lesson => lesson.id === deleted.id );
        this.broadcast();
    }

    toggleLessonViewed(toggled:Lesson) {
        const lesson = _.find(this.lessons, lesson => lesson.id === toggled.id);

        lesson.completed = ! lesson.completed;
        this.broadcast();


    }

    broadcast() {
        this.lessonsListSubject.next(_.cloneDeep(this.lessons));
    }
}

export const store = new DataStore();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can cast the returning value from `asObservable`:

```
public lessonsList$: Observable<Lesson[]> =
    this.lessonsListSubject.asObservable() as Observable<Lesson[]>;
```

This way, typescript will cast the `Observable<{}>` type to a `Observable<Lesson[]>`

Comment: Looks like there is an update to RxJs as the tutorial I was following had exact same implementation as I had.Thanks for your help !

Comment: @ChanchalKumar it's not recommended to use cast here. You should consider declaring the type of your subject, else typescript won't check the emitted type when there are type errors.

Comment: Thats really a nice tip thanks for it ! I will follow it .

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare the type of `lessonsListSubject` like below:

```
private lessonsListSubject: Subject<Lesson[]> = new Subject();
// or
private lessonsListSubject = new Subject<Lesson[]>();
```